# Angular js routing is hindering to load css and js in an php file

Tags: php, css, angularjs

```
  I have a code in which there are three files first is the main one named test.php
```

then others two files are called based on routing......

```
 My angular js file is as follows:-
 angular.module('formApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router'])

  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

    // route to show our basic form (/form)
    .state('form', {
        url: '/form',
        templateUrl: 'form1.php',
        controller: 'formController'
    })

    // nested states 
    // each of these sections will have their own view
    // url will be nested (/form/profile)
    .state('need', {
        url: '/need',
        templateUrl: 'form2.php'
    });

    // url will be /form/interests


       $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/form');
 })
```

// our controller for the form
     .controller('formController', function($scope) {

```
  $scope.formData = {};

  $scope.processForm = function() {
    alert('awesome!');
};
```

});

Now I want to load a form on the load of the test.php file by angularjs routing
,but i am unable to load css in form1.php it's part of code that is not loading css is as follows:-

```
                            <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Product type</label>
                             <div class="controls">
<select data-placeholder="Choose Products" name="product_type[]" class="chosen span6" multiple="multiple" tabindex="6">

                                   <optgroup label="Product Type">
                                   <option value="Domain">Domain</option>
                                   <option value="Website">Website</option>
                                   <option value="SMS">SMS</option>
                                   <option value="SEO">SEO</option>
            <option value="digital Marketing">Digital Marketing</option>
            <option value="Website Meintenece">Website Maintenance</option>
            <option value="Domain+website">Domain + Website</option>
                                   <option value="Hosting">Hosting</option>
                                   </optgroup>

                                </select>
                             </div>
                          </div>
```

I am using jquery.chosen plugin to load it.....

Comment: Help is really needed if someone can..........